# writing `operator=` for non-static reference member class

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, operator-keyword, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar
{
    protected:

public:
        int & x;
        Bar(int & new_x)
        :x(new_x)
        {}
        Bar & operator = (const Bar toCopy)
        {
            x = toCopy.x;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int x1(1);
    int x2(2);

    Bar bar = Bar(x1);
    std::cout << bar.x << std::endl;

    bar = Bar(x2);
    std::cout << bar.x << std::endl;

    bar.x = 5;
    std::cout << bar.x << std::endl;

    std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << x2 << std::endl;

}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
5
5
2
```

What I am trying to do is **copy** `x` and save it within the object `bar`.

The output suggests to me that the assignment operator has not done its magic, both in terms of **copying** and taking the value of the new object. I have followed [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-assignment-operator-and-references/).

Changing `x` into a value rather than a reference is not possible, as in the real program `x` is an abstract class.

Please if possible abstain from using heap assignment.

**EDIT**:
1. I realized that I have just butchered the C++ language. I would like to apologize to all "C++ian" speaking computers. My motivation was to assign a member abstract variable on the stack. As far as I understand, it cannot be done on the stack, because the size of the derived class is not known at compile time.
2. OK... I am a total n00b...(no sh*t, Sherlock!). "Effective C++ programming" @rhalbersma is a must have. It contains essentials, yet you wont find them anywhere (copy constructions, copy initializer),.. in one place anyway.

Comment: public reference data, passing arguments by non-const reference or const value: you might start reading Effective C++ or similar to get your basic class members right.

Comment: I never use references as members, I use pointers instead, you can still do everything (initialize the pointer with &new_x for instance) and more. Some people like references as members because of how restricted they are...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References can be confusing.  So can `const` pointers.  I'll try to clear things up by talking about both of them at the same time.  What can I say, I'm an optimist.

First, `const` pointers.

We'll start with a class called `Foo`.  We can have a pointer to this class -- a `Foo*`.  We can have a pointer to a `const` instance of this class -- a `Foo const*`.  And we can have a `const` pointer to a non-`const` instance of this class -- a `Foo*const`.

A `Foo const*` is a pointer you *can* change to data you cannot change.

A `Foo*const` is a pointer you cannot change to data you *can* change.

I'll assume you got that.  I am, after all, an optimist.  Next, lets look at references.

While it is true that references are aliases, sometimes it helps to think about them in a world where things have concrete implementations in terms of other types.

A `Foo&` is analogous to a `Foo*const` -- a non-changeable "pointer" to an instance of `Foo` you can change.  So the `Foo` you are talking about is always the same one, but you can change its state.

Now, it is a bit more than that.  There is some syntactic sugar.  When you create a reference to another variable, it does the `&` automatically -- so when you do a `Foo& f = a;`, this is analogous to `Foo*const f = &a;`.

Second, when you use `.`, it does the same as `->` in the pointer case.  (And similarly for (most?) other operators)

Third, when you do assignment, it clearly cannot change the pointer's value -- because it is `const` -- but instead it changes the value of the thing pointed to.  So `Foo& f = a; a = b;` does the equivalent of `Foo*const f = &a; *f = b;`.

It assigns the thing *pointed* to, rather than the pointer, when you use `operator=`.  But when you initialize it, it doesn't use `operator=`, even if you have a `=` token.

Initialization is not the same as assignment in general, and the semantics of what happens with a `&` reference and a `*` pointer in initialization and assignment are very different.

`Foo& f = a; f = b;` does two completely different things.  Initialization of a reference initializes the "`const` pointer" portion -- assignment to a reference modifies the thing *pointed to*.

My personal name for how initialization and assignment mean different things with references is "reference semantics", as opposed to "pointer semantics" where both initialization and assignment change what thing is being pointed to.  In "reference semantics", initialization picks what thing is being pointed to, and assignment changes the state of the thing that is pointed to.

This is highly confusing, and I hope I helped make it confusing in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

`Bar bar = Bar(x1);` is not assignment, but *copy-initialization*. It calls the copy constructor, not the copy assignment operator.

The problem though is that you don't understand reference - the member `Bar::x` is just an alias for another variable. Assigning something to it will also modify the original one.

Comment: reference is not my first choice, but I need to get around the fact that in my real program x is of an abstract class type

Answer (score 0):

The `x` inside `bar` is *the same variable* as the one called "x1" in `main`.
That's what references do - they take a variable and give it another name that you can use to refer to it.
Whatever you do to that variable under this new name is the same as doing it under any other name.

First, after

```
Bar bar = Bar(x1);
```

(which is copy initialization, not assignment)
"bar.x" refers to the same variable as the "x" inside the anonymous object on the right hand side, which in turn is a different name for "x1" in main.

After this, the name "bar.x" refers to the same variable as the name "x1".

The line

```
bar = Bar(x2);
```

assigns the value (i.e., 2) of the anonymous object's `x`, which is the same variable as `x2`, to the variable that is called "x" inside `bar`, but whose name is "x1" in `main`.

The line

```
bar.x = 5;
```

then assigns the value 5 to the variable whose name is "bar.x" which, again, is the same variable as "x1" in main.

You cannot make it refer to a different variable.
If you want something that can refer to different variables, you must use a pointer.